# Code in main.cpp works but when I put it in a class it doesn't

Tags: c++, class, opengl

I have some simple code that draws a 30x30 ball to the screen. It worked perfectly when it was all inside of main.cpp, but when I put it into its own separate class I got a very faint grey box taking up the top right of the screen instead. When I paste the exact code I have inside of my Ball class into main.cpp it works perfectly again.

When the code is in the Ball class:
[image]

When I paste all of the code from the Ball class into main (and how it was before the Ball class):
[image]

The code can be found [here.](https://github.com/Bumrang/PongOut/tree/master/src)

[main.cpp](https://github.com/Bumrang/PongOut/blob/master/src/main.cpp)

```
#include "Includes.hpp"

static unsigned int Width = 800;
static unsigned int Height = 600;


int main()
{   

bool CursorEnabled = true;
bool PolygonMode = false;

//Camera.CameraInit(45.0f , Width , Height , Model);   use ortho instead \/
Camera.CameraInit (Width, Height, glm::mat4 (1.0f));

GLuint vao;
glGenVertexArrays (1 , &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

Ball ball;

float LastTime = glfwGetTime(); // (for deltatime)

while (true)
{
    float DeltaTime = glfwGetTime() - LastTime; // Deltatime init
    LastTime = glfwGetTime(); // update for deltatime

    glClearColor (0.0f , 0.0f , 0.0f , 1.0f);
    glClear (GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    ball.Draw();

    glfwSwapBuffers();

    if (glfwGetKey (GLFW_KEY_ESC) || !glfwGetWindowParam(GLFW_OPENED))
    {
        std::cout << "\nShutdown command. Exiting...\n" << std::flush;
        return 0;
    }


}
```

}

[Ball.hpp](https://github.com/Bumrang/PongOut/blob/master/src/Ball.hpp)

```
#ifndef BALL
#define BALL

class Ball
{
private:
//Vertices and UV coordiantes.
std::vector <glm::vec2> ballVert;
std::vector <glm::vec2> ballUV;

//Buffers
GLuint vertBuf;
GLuint uvBuf;

//Image
GLuint ballTex;

//IDs for the shader.
GLuint shader;
GLuint MVPid;
GLuint sampler;
GLuint coord;
GLuint uv;

public:
//Constructor
Ball();

void Draw();

};

#endif
```

[Ball.cpp](https://github.com/Bumrang/PongOut/blob/master/src/Ball.cpp)

```
#include "Includes.hpp"

Ball::Ball()
{
//Create ball vertices and UV coords
ballVert.push_back(glm::vec2(0 , 0));                                       /*left      /\*/
ballVert.push_back(glm::vec2(0 , 30));                                      /*right    /  \*/
ballVert.push_back(glm::vec2(30 , 0));                                      /*top     ------*/

ballVert.push_back(glm::vec2(0 , 30));                                       /*left      /\*/
ballVert.push_back(glm::vec2(30 , 30));                                      /*right    /  \*/
ballVert.push_back(glm::vec2(30 , 0));                                       /*top     ------*/

ballUV.push_back(glm::vec2(0 , 1));
ballUV.push_back(glm::vec2(0 , 0));
ballUV.push_back(glm::vec2(1 , 1));

ballUV.push_back(glm::vec2(0 , 0));
ballUV.push_back(glm::vec2(1 , 0));
ballUV.push_back(glm::vec2(1 , 1));

//Load the image
ballTex = SOIL_load_OGL_texture (
"img/ball.png",
SOIL_LOAD_AUTO,
SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS | SOIL_FLAG_INVERT_Y | SOIL_FLAG_NTSC_SAFE_RGB | SOIL_FLAG_COMPRESS_TO_DXT);

//Generate buffers
glGenBuffers (1 , &vertBuf);
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , vertBuf);
glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , ballVert.size() * sizeof(glm::vec2) , &ballVert[0] , GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenBuffers (1 , &uvBuf);
glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , uvBuf);
glBufferData (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , ballUV.size() * sizeof (glm::vec2) , &ballUV[0] , GL_STATIC_DRAW);

shader = Game.LoadShaders ("src/glsl/ball.vert" , "src/glsl/ball.frag");
MVPid = glGetUniformLocation (shader , "MVP");
sampler = glGetUniformLocation (shader, "sampler");
coord = glGetAttribLocation(shader, "coord");
uv = glGetAttribLocation (shader, "uv");


}

void Ball::Draw()
{
glUseProgram (shader);
    glUniformMatrix4fv(MVPid, 1, GL_FALSE, &Camera.GetMVP()[0][0]); // Send MVP     to shader

    glActiveTexture (GL_TEXTURE0); // bind the ball texture
    glBindTexture (GL_TEXTURE_2D, ballTex);
    glUniform1i (sampler , 0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray (coord); // sending the vertex data
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertBuf);
                glVertexAttribPointer(
                    coord, // The attribute we want to configure
                    2,                  // size
                    GL_FLOAT,           // type
                    GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
                    0,                  // stride
                    (void*)0            // array buffer offset
                    );

        glEnableVertexAttribArray (uv);
            glBindBuffer (GL_ARRAY_BUFFER , uvBuf);
                glVertexAttribPointer (uv, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0,     (void*)0);

    // Draw the triangle !
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, ballVert.size()); 

        glDisableVertexAttribArray(coord);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(uv);
}
```

Comment: post the code we need to see(not the entire project). try and pinpoint the exact problem you're having.

Comment: Where is function main in the second version?

Comment: In the second version (the one with everything inside, no Ball class) looks like this: http://pastebin.com/AC15gnFv

Comment: Here: https://github.com/Bumrang/PongOut/blob/master/src/Engine.cpp

Comment: Yeah, but where is Engine constructor relative to `main()`? I suspect you don't have a valid context at the time when Ball is constructed, though I don't have enough information to prove it.

Comment: Engine and Camera are constructed with the global include file: https://github.com/Bumrang/PongOut/blob/master/src/Includes.hpp

Comment: Man never create globals in such cases. I don't have time to search through everything you posted but just get rid of unneeded globals and your problems will probably be solved.